# Applying a "filter" on the Get-ADComputer Powershell Command

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

In short, what I'm trying to do is, run a command that will capture the names of a set of computers and then output the results into a text file. Note how I said a "set of computers", for this, I am aware that a filter must be applied. I have applied a filter, but the output file literally outputs blank!

See my code below:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -eq "GBSU1" } | select Name | out-file C:\Users\adm-arifsohm\Desktop\test-folder\computers.txt
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

**Update:**

I was able to work it out in the end. Please see my revised code:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {(Name -like 'GBSU-*') -or (Name -like 'GBSU1*')} | Select -Expand Name | out-file C:\Users\adm-arifsohm\Desktop\test-folder\computers.txt
```

Thanks to all who helped.

Comment: A note for next time you ask a question, write the output you wish to get, that will make it a little easier to anser your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -eq "GBSU1" }
```

This part will match on exactly "GBSU1", and nothing else. If this is the prefix or part of the computer names, you should try:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -like "GBSU1*" }
```

The asterix (*) is the wildcard character, so the line above would like for something like GBSU1somethingelse

Sorry I ran out of time, will come back to explain further if needed, but I think this is your problem

Answer (score 0):

**1'st** off, you need to use some thing else then -eq. EQ will get you one
    object and not a set of objects. In this case that is.

**2'nd** off, you need to tell out-file that it will need to add content to the file, and not rewrite it.
        Here you use the property -Append

> -Append
>   Indicates that the cmdlet adds the output to the end of an existing file, instead of replacing the file contents.

You can allso use -NoClobber, if you wish it, no need.

> -NoClobber
>   Indicates that the cmdlet will not overwrite an existing file. By default, if a file exists in the specified path, Out-File overwrites the file without warning. If both Append and NoClobber are used, the output is appended to the existing file.

It will look like `out-file C:\Users\adm-arifsohm\Desktop\test-folder\computers.txt -Append`

**3'nd** off, if the path you are linking to, is not located on the disk, it can't find the path, and it will give you this error  `Out-File : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\adm-arifsohm\Desktop\test-folder\computers.txt'.`

What the code will look like is the following:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -like 'GBSU1*' } | select Name | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\adm-arifsohm\Desktop\test-folder\computers.txt" -Append
```

This will take any computers starting with GBSU1 and put it in the file. You can all so move the start in front of the name '*GBSU1', and all computers ending this GBSU1 will do put in the file.

In the end, I would write the code as this:

```
$FilePath = 'C:\Users\adm-arifsohm\Desktop\test-folder'
$Filename = 'computers.txt'

if (-not (Test-Path $FilePath)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $FilePath -Force
} else {}

Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -like 'mth24*2' } -Properties name | Out-File -FilePath $($FilePath + "\" + $Filename ) -Append -Force
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, the first suggestion worked, though the presence of a lot of spaces was rather worrying. The second suggestion didn't work for me, again, it outputted blank.

Comment: Can you write what you tryed and didn't work, and I will have a look at it? Can you allso tell me what you are looking for, so I can think in how the filtering will need to be?

Answer (score 0):

Get-ADComputer -filter {name -like "GBSU*" -and Enabled -eq "true" } | out-file C:\Users\adm-arifsohm\Desktop\test-folder\computers.txt

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but unfortunately, this extracts multiple lines of information, whereas, I only required the computer name. I have sorted it now, please see the revised code in my initial post.

Comment: Nice observation.  Having the extra lines dumped out by default makes it fairly hard on the eyes.  So I've actually used your modification to improve almost the same script I'm working on.  Get-ADComputer -filter {name -like "win10*" -and Enabled -eq "true" } | Select -expand Name | out-file C:\Users\Admin1\Desktop\computers.txt

Answer (score 0):

After extensive testing I discovered this very odd solution to using PowerShell 'get-adcomputer' with a wildcard filter:
get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like '*$computer*'"
##The reason this is odd is that single quotes are not supposed to be able to translate a variable##

Comment: Please provide your question in the form of a question.